# How to develop app for iOS that communicate with devices that support Serial Port Profile via classic Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, spp

I want to develop app for iOS that communicate with devices that support Serial Port Profile via classic Bluetooth. But I cannot find documents for SPP.

I know, a few things about that. If a vender X sells the some hardware that support SPP, then I only get some SDK from vender X and develop an app with vender X's protocol. But in that case, my app could not deal with the other devices that support SPP.

What should I do ?

1. gathering all SDKs for devices that support SPP in the world and develop an app with them.
2. developing an app with hidden apis for SPP, classic Bluetooth but no info.
3. getting MFi program but I have no ideas after register it.

thanks for your reading.

Comment: You can only support SPP on MFI devices via external connectivity framework. You need to add the vendor identifiers to your info.plist in order to work with those devices. Most development is being done on BLE as it doesn't have those requirements.

Comment: external connectivity framework ?is it external accessory framework ?

Comment: sorry, yes, my mistake